# How to call the newInstance method correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my first fragment i write next code:

```
viewModel.showConnectionsSelectorFragmentEvent.observe(this, Observer<List<ConnectionViewModel>> {
    val selectConnectionsFragment = SelectConnectionsFragment()
    selectConnectionsFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 555)
    activity?.addFragment(SelectConnectionsFragment.newInstance(connections = it))
})
```

And here is the problem, idk how to call newInstance from my `val selectConnectionsFragment`.
in my fragment for newInstance i have next code and it works fine:

```
companion object {
    const val KEY_CONNECTIONS = "CONNECTIONS"

    fun newInstance(connections: List<ConnectionViewModel>): SelectConnectionsFragment {
        val arrayList = ArrayList<ConnectionViewModel>(connections)
        return SelectConnectionsFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable(KEY_CONNECTIONS, arrayList)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to invoke the `newInstance` method just like a traditional Java-like static method, i.e. `ClassName.newInstance`. Which class is the companion object related to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can just call `SelectConnectionsFragment.newInstance(...)` and assign it to `selectConnectionsFragment`:

```
viewModel.showConnectionsSelectorFragmentEvent.observe(this, Observer<List<ConnectionViewModel>> {
    val selectConnectionsFragment = SelectConnectionsFragment.newInstance(connections = it)
    selectConnectionsFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 555)
    activity?.addFragment(selectConnectionsFragment)
})
```